# Display multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I just want to display the following array in php .How it possible. Please help

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_ID] => 1
                [category_name] => System Reporting
                [category_desc] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [myiparq_permission_ID] => 7
                        [permission_display_name] => Enforcement Read

                    )



            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_ID] => 2
                [category_name] => Administrative Access

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [myiparq_permission_ID] => 3
                        [permission_display_name] => Enforcement Admin

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [myiparq_permission_ID] => 10
                        [permission_display_name] => Application Review/Approval

                    )



            )

    )
```

)

Comment: If you want it on a webpage then `echo "<pre>" . print_r(Array()) . "</pre>";` else just `print_r(Array());`.

Comment: I don`t want print all array.Just want to display category and its subcategory under that particular category. Just like Enforcement Read under System Reporting and Enforcement Admin under  Administrative Access and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($your_array_name);
echo'</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
for ($i = 0; $i = $alength - 1; $i++){
    echo(/*whatever*/);
    $blength = count($array[$i]);
    for($j =0; $j = $blength -1; $j++){
        echo(/*whatever*/);
        /* and so on... */
    }
}
```

Or didnt I understand it right?

Comment: how to find $blength?

Comment: $alength is the length of the array
`$alength = count($array);` and so is $blength, just one step below : `$blength = count($array[$i]);`